# Maintain Undo In Modified, Bound, NSAttributedString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, undo

I've got an attributed string bound to a NSTextView. I'm using a method that is called (using KVO) every time the string is edited to add background color attributes to string based on a regEx match. I do this by creating a new mutable attributed string with `-initWithAttributedString:` then `-beginEditing`, `-addAttribute:`, `-endEditing`. Once I've added all the background color attributes I want, I call the string's setter `[self setTextViewString:mutableAttributedString]` The issue is, that if there actually are any attributes added to the string, it kills undo and moves the cursor to the end of the string.

How can I maintain undo? I've maintained cursor position by calling the textView's selectedRanges and setSelectedRanges: methods on either side of the setter, but this still seems a bit hackish.

I wasn't able to bind the textview directly to the mutableattributedstring, but it seems like there should be a more direct way to modify the bound string so it doesn't mess up editing.

PS, the addition of attributes happens after the KVO method finishes by calling `-performSelectorOnMainThread:` It was the only way I could get the added attributes to display.

Answer (score 0):

> `[self setTextView:mutableAttributedString]`

Pardon? You're setting your `textView` to an attributed string? Wouldn't it make more sense to keep your text view there?

Try getting the text view's `textStorage` and replacing its contents with the new attributed string by sending the text storage a `setAttributedString:` message.

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear and I changed it to make more sense. I have my textview bound to an attributed string so I am calling the *string's* setter, not a setter for the textview itself.